# "Decimate" doesn't change the face count in blender

Tags: blenderkit

I have a .obj formed data from ShapeNet, and I want to decimate the mesh from 32600 faces to about 800 faces (don't worry about the detail loss). But the face count doesn't change at all however I change the ratio.
I've also tried un-subdivide and planar decimation, it doesn't work as well.

Strangely, when I try decimation on other model, (for example, a cube), the decimation works.

I suppose it's because of the data, but I can't figure out why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the mesh connected? Maybe go into edit mode, select all and marge by distance.